# How to make use of ios 7 default icons

Tags: ios, uibutton

Am creating a music player and am currently using UIButton with background image of play icon. Is it possible to make use of the default ios 7 play icon instead. I would really appreciate if I can learn how to make use of those native icons instead of using images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it makes sense for your project, you could use a toolbar; and then add more bar buttons items and set their identifiers (like Rewind, Play, Pause, Fast Forward). Use the Fixed Space Bar button item if you want to leave some space between them.